# Select all employees sorted by last name in ascending order

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

How can I implement SQL query in order to select all employees sorted by last name in ascending order in the following Java class:

```
public class SqlQueries {
    //Select all employees sorted by last name in ascending order
    //language=HSQLDB
    String select = "";
}
```

Comment: Maybe something like `"SELECT * FROM Employees ORDER BY last_name ASC"`. I think these guides have what you want: [SQL ORDERBY](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-order-by/) and [JDBC ORDERBY tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sorting-data.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a separate column for last name then it is very much easy to achieve.

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE ORDER BY LAST_NAME ASC;
```

If there is only one column i.e. full name , then split the string from the last white space and extract the last name.

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE ORDER BY SUBSTR(FULL_NAME,INSTR(FULL_NAME,' ',-1)) ASC;
```